# Changing Taskbar size

Tags: c#

Everytime I boot my pc, the taskbar goes to size 2. But I'd like to have it on 3, so I always have to change it. Any way of how I can code a program in c#-ConsoleApplication that does that for me? So I can code that and put it into shell:startup, so it does it automatically everytime I boot my pc.

Comment: I would imagine you could do this by editing the registry.  Probably far less work than writing a program.